# Error #153 Another process has added 'Note' record. Your changes will be lost(SalesOrderEntry)

Tags: acumatica

In the Sales Order page, I created a custom button which purpose is to save and refresh the page. Currently it saves fine and processes the new order to an order number but when I try to add an item/edit or perform an action in the drop down menu I receive the error message.

Here's my code:

```
public PXAction<SOOrder> SRefresh;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "S RefreshT")]
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    protected virtual IEnumerable sRefresh(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
     SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
     Base.Actions.PressSave();

     SOLine sLine = PXSelect<SOLine, Where<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOLine.orderNbr>>>>.Select(graph, this.Base.Document.Current.OrderNbr);

     if (sLine != null && sLine.InventoryID.HasValue)
       {
        graph.Document.Current = graph.Document.Search<SOLine.orderNbr>(sLine.OrderNbr);
        throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, null);

       }

       return adapter.Get();
    }
```

I've also tried using graph.Persist() as said in the manual instead of Action.PressSave(); with no success.

I appreciate any input you guys may have, Thank you

Comment: You're executing this from the sales order graph - why in this case are you trying to create a new instance of SOOrderEntry, and then try to redirect user to that new instance (which happens to be the same page?) You're most likely getting this error because of a concurrency problem; similar to two users working on the same document. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but most likely all you need to do is work with the Base object.

Comment: The goal is to save/refresh and run a trigger for a specific field on a order number(or new number) on the sales order graph. When you mention the base object I'm not quite sure I understand which base object. Should I just be working with the Sales Order entry graph? Thank you for your response.

Comment: Have you completed the standard Acumatica developer trainings (T100/T200/T300) ? "Base" is an instance of SOOrderEntry. Base.Document.Current contains a reference to the current SOOrder, and Base.Transactions contains the list of SOLine of this document. Another problem I also found in your code is that you're calling Document.Search and passing <SOLine.orderNbr> as field reference; it should be <SOOrder.orerNbr> in this case - but you won't need to search for the current document if you just work with the current graph, as Base.Document.Current will already be the document you're looking at.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I am trying to get through the guide as quickly as I can to get up to speed as I am a new hire. Thank you so much for responding so quickly to the issue and the explanation was clear and concise. I was able to fix my code and implement it based on the information you gave me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'll post an answer, please accept it so that the question no longer shows as unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working with the current sales order, you don't need to create a new instance of the sales order entery graph and redirect your user. You can work with the `Base` object and run all your logic on it.

`Base.Document.Current` contains a reference to the current `SOOrder`, and `Base.Transactions` contains the list of `SOLine` of this document. Another problem I also found in your code is that you're calling `Document.Search<SOline.orderNbr>`; it should be `SOOrder.orerNbr` since you're searching inside the Document view, which contains sales orders, and not lines. In this case, it's not even necessary to search, `Base.Document.Current` will already be set to the order you're looking at.

I strongly recommend completing the standard Acumatica developer trainings - T100, T200, T300; this stuff is all covered and will get you productive quickly

Comment: Hi Gabriel, so the page does exactly what I intended but there seems to be a discrepancy between the  `throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(Base, null);` and a normal page refresh done by an F5. My trigger runs correctly on a normal F5 refresh, but it doesn't do a full reload of the current page on a `RedirectRequiredExecption` not running the trigger entirely . I was searching through the manuals to for a full page refresh/redirect and I was unable to find it besides the PXredirect.